# Why Vuex doesn't update state inside module?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Using Vue 2. My state isn't updated inside module. I created simplified example of my code.
Store config:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex, { StoreOptions } from "vuex";
import users from "@/store/modules/users";
import test from "@/store/modules/test";
import { vuexfireMutations } from "vuexfire";
import { RootState } from "@/store/types";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store: StoreOptions<RootState> = {
  state: {
    version: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    ...vuexfireMutations
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: { users, /* other modules */ test },
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
};

export default new Vuex.Store<RootState>(store);
```

Individual module (test.ts):

```js
import { RootState, TestState } from "@/store/types";
import { ActionTree, GetterTree, Module, MutationTree } from "vuex";

const getters: GetterTree<TestState, RootState> = {};

const mutations: MutationTree<TestState> = {
  SET_TEST(state, nextState: TestState) {
    console.log("current", state); //shows correct current state
    // let's say nextState is following: { test: "Hi!" }
    console.log("next", nextState); //show correct next state 
    state = { ...state, ...nextState, loaded: true };
  },
};

const actions: ActionTree<TestState, RootState> = {
  setTest({ commit }, payload: TestState) {
    commit("SET_TEST", payload);
  }
};

const test: Module<TestState, RootState> = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    loaded: false
  },
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
};

export default test;
```

After dispatching `setTest` action, everything goes properly through vuex except mutation. Next action payload is exactly what I want but my state for that module still shows `test: { loaded: false }`, but should be: `test: { test: "Hi!", loaded: true"}`

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** assign to the `state` - because you will replace a reactive Object with a non-reactive one.

Instead, create a key/property inside the `state` - and mutate its value.